# Does my hair color in Skyrim affect my werewolf color?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does my hair in Skyrim affect my werewolf color? Simple as that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it does not, the werewolf texture is fixed and does not change with your hair.

See also: Every picture ever of werewolfs in Skyrim ([and the wiki I suppose, but that does not spell it out](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf_(Skyrim))).

Comment: A shame really, I would have loved to see a purple haired (furred?) werewolf running around.

Comment: There is a cool mod so you can change your fur color.
http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/59463/?